# Modify main WordPress loop with a parse_query filter

Tags: query-posts, loop

I am trying to modify the main WordPress loop on my category pages like so:

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'my_modified_query');

function my_modified_query( $q ) {
       if (!is_admin() && is_category()) {
              $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
              $q->set( 'meta_key', 'my_key' );
       }

       return $q;
}
```

but it does not seem to work.

However modifying anything else like :

```
 $q->set( 'order','title' );
 $q->set( 'orderby', 'DESC');
```

works perfectly. Just not

```
$q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$q->set( 'meta_key', 'my_key' );
```

any idea why that is?

Comment: Why are you using `parse_query` instead of the `pre_get_posts` filter?

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately all meta queries get run through `_get_meta_sql`.

- [wp-includes/meta.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L377)

  Line 402 - 403 in the `_get_meta_sql` function

The following coditional statement runs for any meta queries.

```
if ( empty( $meta_key ) && empty( $meta_value ) )
    continue;
```

There's a ticket here for this which outlines what we should be able to do.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16735

What you can do however is purposely pass your query a `meta_value` your posts will never likely have and use the `!=` (not equals) comparison, technically that should get you the right posts, eg..

```
$q->set( 'meta_key', 'my_key' );
$q->set( 'meta_value', 'WPSE_RULES!' );
$q->set( 'meta_compare', '!=' );
$q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
```

There's one further thing though, you've got these the wrong way round before..

```
$q->set( 'order','title' );
$q->set( 'orderby', 'DESC');
```

- `order` sets the which direction to order the results by, valid values are `asc` or `desc` (upper or lowercase).
- `orderby` sets what to the order the results by, eg. date, title, meta value, etc..

I didn't mention that there's actually a new method for querying posts based on meta now, using the `meta_query` parameter, but seeing as that won't avoid the problem i've mentioned above and older meta parameters still(in the end) get converted into a `meta_query` anyway, i'll simply offer up a link to some examples.

http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Hope that all helps.. :)

Comment: I got 2 replies! That really made my day (I usually ask things and never get replies, he, he). I'll definetely try what you suggest. Thanks for that. I know about the order and ordeby switch, that was accidental but thanks for pointing that out too :)

Comment: Note, you can(or should be able to) use `set_query_var` inside `parse_query` filters, which basicailly does the same as `$q->set` is just looks prettier... :)

Comment: Ok, so I tried everything suggested but nothing seems to sort my posts with the specifc custom field but I can say that I managed to make it work using the add_filter('request', 'my_modified_query'); Still cannot understand why the same function would not work on the add_filter('parse_query', 'my_modified_query'); which is a shame as I loose the ability to use conditional tags :(

Comment: Just before the end of the `parse_query` filter add something like `update_option( 'problem_vars', $q->query_vars );` for one page load, then print it out somewhere.. `print '<pre>';print_r( get_option( 'problem_vars' ) );print '</pre>';` and check all the query vars are as they should be..

Comment: @ t31os, Thanks for this! Well, still nothing :( I can see that my variables are filled correctly: `[orderby] => meta_value` and `[meta_key] => price` but no results whatsoever (posts in that category have the "price" custom field set so I should get some results!) This can't be a bug can't it? Especially when the filtering works on the **request** filter.

Answer (score 1):

you probably got the solution as it passed almost an year since you have posted. 
I had the same issue few hours ago until I have figured it out that I was using numbers - so I used `meta_value_num` insted of `meta_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Servus Sarah. I guess this is for one of your envato-shop themes? Have you already tried to print the query like this (before return): `echo '<pre>'; print_r($q); echo '</pre>';`.

I guess you're adding this inside a themes functions.php?

`$q->set( 'oderby', 'DESC' );` works, but `$q->set( 'oderby', 'meta_value' );` not? Try using two basic orderby parameters separated by spaces to check if the default behavior works all over. If yes, you might just run into some misspelling. Do other values aside from 'my_key' work for 'meta_key'? If not, then maybe you're missing a 'meta_value' parameter. Not sure on this one, but take a look at this one: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters or even better a direct look at the function inside the core file.

Comment: Servus kaiser, seems you know me :) Wish I knew who you are too! I triple checked the spelling but it all seems good. It bugs me that I cannot find what it is. I'll check again though. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Danke!  Schon gemacht! :)